# Equivalent Xml for Json

Tags: json, xml

I came across this service from stackoverflow

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions?fromdate=1519862400&todate=1522368000&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&tagged=python

I believe the source is from a database. **How do I build an Xml to spit me out data in similar format?**

I use the below logical lines

xmldoc.Load(xmlFileName);
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConver.SerializeXmlNode(xmldoc);

Any recommendation of how to build the Xml which is a reverse process? My solutions are heavily dependant on Xml and flatFiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://api.stackexchange.com/docs the StackExchange API only supports JSON output, not XML. So you will have to convert the JSON to XML.

My own preference is to do this conversion "by hand" using XSLT 3.0 rather than using a standard library, because standard libraries often give you XML that's rather difficult to work with.

Comment: Any links on how this is done?

Comment: Thanks Michael. I was using Excel and Newtonsoft for the conversion.

Comment: As you said, I built it by hand and used Xslt to tweak it the way, it was required